# Bootstrap doesn't show up properly in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, laravel, bootstrap-4

I setup bootstrap files in public folder. Routes are as below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/tether.min.js')}}"></script>
```

no problem with this. I can see connection to files when I check the source code. and also bootstrap fonts are active but, when I try to copy some examples from bootstrap website. It doesn't display properly. For example I copied navigation bar to my main.blade But it doesn't show up. 
What is causing this? Any idea?

It s big screen but showing responsive hamburger icon? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add jquery before bootstrap min js file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{url('assets/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/jquery.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/tether.min.js')}}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{url('assets/js/bootstrap.min.js')}}"></script>
```

Comment: thank you, but it doesn't solve the problem. still can't display it.

Comment: can you please check is the error still showing or not ?

Comment: it returns this error? `Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether (http://tether.io/)` something is very odd...

Comment: then add tether js before bootstrap js

Comment: okay, update that too errors are lost but there something on with the display. the page is big screen but it shows responsive hamburger bar? https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZoNE.png

Comment: your first question answer is here , but now its an design issue. check your included bootstrap version and you example code which is allocated for an bootstrap version is matched or not. if yes then you have to correct the code

Answer (score 0):

The order in which you add javascript in HTML page is important. In this case since bootstrap.min.js uses jquery.min.js jquery must be added first. So when bootstrap loads and looks for jquery it finds it.

But if one script does not depend on another then you can add them in any order.

So add jquery.min.js first then anything that uses jquery(like bootstrap) after it.

Comment: thank you, made that errors lost but still some problem with the look. it s big screen but responsive hamburger icon is displaying. https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZoNE.png